# Problems when scraping in python by using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I started scraping in python  usually in most cases almost 99% of the stuff works.
But i do encounter problems that i think shouldnt happen (because when i try the same scraping by using other languages i succeeded ).

I will try to post some examples of specific sites for each problem.

one problem is for some sites i can scrape using http but it fails for https and for others it fails for https and doesnt for http.  Also some times i would get one response code for http and 200 for https or vs versa.   How could i change it so that i would be able to always scrape for 'http'?  as i managed doing it in other languages.

example :

```
res=requests.get('http://{}'.format("asmc.com"), headers=headers, allow_redirects = True)
number= str(res.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
title=soup.title.string
title
```

the above code for this site 'asmc.com' works only if i use https and not if i use http. Why? How do i solve it?

---

second problem is some sites I couldnt scrape either by using http nor with  https even though in other langwges i could.  as these are valid sites having all the html tags

example :

```
res=requests.get('http://{}'.format("alljobs.co.il"), headers=headers, allow_redirects = True)
number= str(res.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
title=soup.title.string
title
```

this alljobs.co.il   site i coldnt find its tag either by using http or https. Why? How do i fix it?

---

if you are curious this is the header i used but even without using it i get same results i just used it for other sites and it did help me. But for these i couldnt find solution.

headers = {
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

Comment: Some sites are https only, and don't have forwarding from http set up...

Comment: And alljobs.co.il has a bunch of Javascript that loads the site, so you'll need to use a JS-aware module like `selenium`.

Comment: thx. But @MattDMo that cant be true here. It happens here and plenty other sites only here on python. When i scrape the sites in different languages it works just fine.  Also you can check the first site does have  forwarding from http and its directed to https you can check its tools.  Lastly i want emphesize that I do get soup and code but cant get the title even though i could get the title using javascript for example.  even when  i used http and not https

Comment: `requests` doesn't parse/execute Javascript, your other scraping engines likely do, *especially* if one of your languages is JS. Try using `selenium` or `phantomjs` instead.

Comment: @MattDMo yes i used JS and there it worked.  How do i use selenium for this do you have a code? i am new to python

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/ and choose the Python options

Comment: Make sure you've downloaded the webdriver for the browser of your choice and that it's in your PATH (or you pass the path when initiating `driver` in your code).

Comment: tried it i get errors doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

> site 'asmc.com' works only if i use https and not if i use http. Why? How do i solve it?

Looks like your only option is to use HTTPS, as the owners are not supporting http. UPDATE: since this `works in another language`, below applies.

> this alljobs.co.il site i coldnt find its tag either by using http or https. Why? How do i fix it?
>
> if you are curious this is the header i used but even without using it i get same results i just used it for other sites and it did help me. But for these i couldn't find solution.

I'd try using **http** in those other languages and python, then add wireshark to capture the traffic inflight and compare the packets' contents.

It's probable that each languages' libraries may add different headers/etc. that influence the website's response.

UPDATE: breaking this idea down further...

1. The internet runs on packets.
2. Libraries translate your request into packets, and
3. different libraries may do this slightly differently.
4. In some corner-cases, websites will misbehave with specific combinations of headers/etc.
5. Wireshark can let you `see` the contents of these (`http-only) packets, so you can compare/contrast the minutiae of how each language constructs the packets they send. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark
6. Use what you've learned (what headers/etc. the website doesn't like) and figure out how to get your library to generate the request packets `just right`...

Comment: As to your first part i dont understand  because it works just fine in other laguages even by using http.  As to your second part "d' try using http in those other languages and python, then add wireshark to capture the traffic inflight and compare the packets' contents."  i dont understant it could you show the code maybe? thx

Comment: It's not a code solution - use the wireshark tool to capture the traffic and see what headers/etc. each language's libraries are sending

Comment: i am not familiar with it. And cant understand what you are talking about sorry.

Comment: ...or just use the other language, if it works over there ‍♂️